# Limit on SSAS drill throughs

Tags: sql-server, ssas

Does any one know if there is a limit on number of drill throughs we can create in one SSAS cube. Currently, i have created 10 but i see only 9 in excel, one of them is missing. I wonder if there is a limit as such. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

there is no such limit, however the list will depend on the context. for example if you define a drill trough on measure group A and are looking at measure group B, then it won't show.

Comment: i am defining both the drill throughs on same measure group. Its strange that one among the 10 drill throughs will disappear for each deployment , some times D1 disappear, some times D2 disappear.